# Can anybody confirm which aircraft is in this picture?

Tags: aircraft-design, aircraft-identification, jet, fighter

[image: Aircraft's nose profile]

[*Image Source*](http://www.autoneuroticfixation.com/2012/09/fighters.html)

Does anyone know what airplane is shown in this picture? It looks like the Republic F-84, but I'm not sure because the front landing gear is under the nose on the F-84 and this one is further back.

Answer (score 14):

Based on what I find from the marking on the plane of "[8-MV](http://www.touchdown-aviation.com/flying-legends/plane/cold-war-jets/dassault-mystere-iv-858-mv.php)", it appears to be a [Dassault Mystère IV A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dassault_Myst%C3%A8re_IV). The image on the non-Wikipedia page looks identical to the one in your image (I can't put that image here because it is copy-protected).

[image]
[Image Source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Dassault_Mystere_IV_(4229072236).jpg)

Comment: Try this image: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Dassault_Mystere_IV_(4229072236).jpg

Comment: I concur. Intake, canopy, rivet lines, and gun port all match.

Comment: Thank you so much...I could not have figured it out without your help!